# How to make an error message for each empty form field

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to display an error message for each empty field, my problem is that when I submit the form with an empty (one or two)  field all the error messages appear. I want only one error message for each empty field to appear, not all of them.

HTML :

```html
<form action="" id="my-form">
  <label for="name">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  <p class="error-field">First Name cannot be empty</p>
  </label>
  
  <label for="last-name">
    <input type="text" id="last-name" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <p class="error-field">Last Name cannot be empty</p>
  </label>
  
  <label for="email">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <p class="error-field">Looks like this is not an email</p>
  </label>

  <label for="password">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <p class="error-field">Password cannot be empty</p>
  </label>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="form-button">Claim your free trial </button>
  <p>By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <a href="" class="terms-conditions-link">Terms and Services</a></p>
  
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
const submitButton = document.querySelector('.form-button');
const errorField = document.querySelectorAll(".error-field");
const validate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const firstName = document.getElementById("name");
  const lastName = document.getElementById("last-name");
  const email = document.getElementById("email");
  const password = document.getElementById("password");

  if(firstName.value < 1 ) {
    errorField.forEach((f) => f.classList.toggle('error-active'));
    errorField.forEach((c) => c.style.color = "red");
    firstName.classList.toggle("invalid");
    return false;
  }

  if (lastName.value < 1) {
    errorField.forEach((f) => f.classList.toggle("error-active"));
    errorField.forEach((c) => (c.style.color = "red"));
    lastName.classList.toggle("invalid");
    return false;
  } 

  if (email.value < 1) {
    errorField.forEach((f) => f.classList.toggle("error-active"));
    errorField.forEach((c) => (c.style.color = "red"));
    email.classList.toggle("invalid");
    return false;
  }
  
  if (password.value < 1) {
    errorField.forEach((f) => f.classList.toggle("error-active"));
    errorField.forEach((c) => (c.style.color = "red"));
    password.classList.toggle("invalid");
    return false;
  } else {
    password.classList.remove("invalid");
    errorField.classList.remove("error-active");
  }

  return true;
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click' , validate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this fixed your issue. Notice, password changed to passwordD and you were accessing all the error field without specifying which

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('.form-button');
const errorField = document.querySelectorAll(".error-field");
const validate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const firstName = document.getElementById("name");
  const lastName = document.getElementById("last-name");
  const email = document.getElementById("email");
  const passwordD = document.getElementById("password");

  if (firstName.value < 1) {
    errorField[0].classList.toggle('error-active');
    errorField[0].style.color = "red";
    firstName.classList.toggle("invalid");
    
  }

  if (lastName.value < 1) {
    errorField[1].classList.toggle("error-active");
    errorField[1].style.color = "red";
    lastName.classList.toggle("invalid");
    
  }

  if (email.value < 1) {
    errorField[2].classList.toggle("error-active");
    errorField[2].style.color = "red";
    email.classList.toggle("invalid");
    
  }

  if (password.value < 1) {
    errorField[3].classList.add("error-active");
    errorField[3].style.color = "red";
    passwordD.classList.toggle("invalid");
    
  } else {
    passwordD.classList.remove("invalid");

    errorField.forEach((f) => {
      f.classList.remove("error-active");
      f.style.color = "black";
    });
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', validate);
```

```html
<form action="" id="my-form">
  <label for="name">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  <p class="error-field">First Name cannot be empty</p>
  </label>

  <label for="last-name">
    <input type="text" id="last-name" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <p class="error-field">Last Name cannot be empty</p>
  </label>

  <label for="email">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <p class="error-field">Looks like this is not an email</p>
  </label>

  <label for="password">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <p class="error-field">Password cannot be empty</p>
  </label>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="form-button">Claim your free trial </button>
  <p>By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <a href="" class="terms-conditions-link">Terms and Services</a></p>

</form>
```

Comment: I tried indexing  at first but for some reason it didn't worked, I must have missed something. It works now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a form validation JS plugin instead of reinveting the wheel, for example [Form Validation Plugin](https://formvalidation.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code a bit using a class for the inputs, and keeping track of an `isValid` boolean for the form. You were setting all error-fields with your code. Here, we are able to reference just the error-field that applies using `closest()` to find the encompassing `label`, then `querySelector` to find the error-field

```
 el.closest('label').querySelector('.error-field');
```

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('.form-button');
const validate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let isValid = true
  document.querySelectorAll('.validate').forEach(el => {
    let error = el.closest('label').querySelector('.error-field').classList;
    if (el.value.trim().length === 0) {
      isValid = false;
      error.add('error-active');
      el.classList.add('invalid')
    } else {
      error.remove('error-active');
      el.classList.remove('invalid')
    }
  })
  return isValid;
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', validate);
```

```css
.error-field.error-active,
input.invalid{
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="my-form">
  <label for="name">
        <input type="text" id="name" class='validate' name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
      <p class="error-field">First Name cannot be empty</p>
      </label>
  <label for="last-name">
        <input type="text" id="last-name" class='validate' name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
        <p class="error-field">Last Name cannot be empty</p>
      </label>
  <label for="email">
        <input type="email" id="email" class='validate' name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <p class="error-field">Looks like this is not an email</p>
      </label>
  <label for="password">
        <input type="password" id="password" class='validate' name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <p class="error-field">Password cannot be empty</p>
      </label>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="form-button">Claim your free trial </button>
  <p>By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <a href="" class="terms-conditions-link">Terms and Services</a></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because inside each if statement you are looping through all the Error fields in the form and update it all. So what you can do is first add unique id for each dom entry in the HTML file such as err-password, error-name and so on then inside each if statement grab the relevant eror field that needs to show the error and update only that field.

Answer (score 0):

Using [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) would simplify your code a lot here... Since the error message always is right after the `input`.

In the condition to show or not the error.. That is the `value.length` you have to check.

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('.form-button');
const errorField = document.querySelectorAll(".error-field");

const validate = (e) => {
  
  // Remove any already displayed error
  errorField.forEach(function(error){
    error.classList.remove("invalid");
  })
  
  // Loop through all inputs to check the value length
  document.querySelectorAll("form input").forEach(function(input){
    if(input.value.length < 1){
      input.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("invalid");
    }
  })
  
  // Prevent submit only if there are errors shown
  let errorCount = document.querySelectorAll(".error-field.invalid").length
  if(errorCount){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click' , validate);
```

```css
label{
  display: block;
}

label p{
  margin: 0;
}

.error-field{
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

.invalid{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="my-form">
  <label for="name">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  <p class="error-field">First Name cannot be empty</p>
  </label>
  
  <label for="last-name">
    <input type="text" id="last-name" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <p class="error-field">Last Name cannot be empty</p>
  </label>
  
  <label for="email">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <p class="error-field">Looks like this is not an email</p>
  </label>

  <label for="password">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <p class="error-field">Password cannot be empty</p>
  </label>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="form-button">Claim your free trial </button>
  <p>By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <a href="" class="terms-conditions-link">Terms and Services</a></p>
  
</form>
```